# how to calculate standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have the following chart.
How do I calculate the standard deviation?
I've tried to do that:

$x=$ $[2^2*30+6^2*35+(9.5)^2*10+13.5^2*20+18^2*5)] \over 100 $  $-(7.25)^2$= **22.912** -> wrong answer.
what did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: You have $5^2$ where you should have $(13.5)^2$. Is $7.25$ the correct mean? Now I get 22.9125, not 22.912

Comment: The standard deviation is the square root of the value you have obtained.

Comment: sorry it was a typo, the 7.25 mean is from the book I didnt calculate it

Comment: @mfl it should be equal to 23.4 and I got 22.912

Comment: Dividing by $99$ instead of $100$, to get the square of the [corrected sample standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation), we get $23.144$. Is that the answer expected?

Comment: @robjohn its close enough :D thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a table of samples, we should use the [corrected sample standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation) whose square is divided by $n-1$ instead of $n$. This gives the square of the standard deviation to be $23.1439$ instead of $22.9125$.